# Sum of linear time algorithms is linear time?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Pardon me if the question is "silly". I am new to algorithmic time complexity.

I understand that if I have n numbers and I want to sum them, it takes "n steps", which means the algorithm is O(n) or linear time. i.e. Number of steps taken increases linearly with number of input, n.

If I write a new algorithm that does this summing 5 times, one after another, I understand that it is O(5n) = O(n) time, still linear (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant)).

**Question**

If I have say 10 different O(n) time algorithms (sum, linear time sort etc). And I run them one after another on the n inputs.

Does this mean that overall this runs in O(10n) = O(n), linear time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, *O(kn)* for any **constant** *k*, = *O(n)*

If you start growing your problem and decide that your 10 linear ops are actually k linear ops based on, say k being the length of a user input array, it would then be incorrect to drop that information from the big-oh

Answer (score 3):

It's best to work it through from the definition of big-O, then learn the rule of thumb once you've "proved" it correct.

If you have 10 `O(n)` algorithms, that means that there are 10 constants C<sub>1</sub> to C<sub>10</sub>, such that for each algorithm A<sub>i</sub>, the time taken to execute it is less than C<sub>i</sub> * n for sufficiently large n.

Hence[*] the time taken to run all 10 algorithms for sufficiently large n is less than:

C<sub>1</sub> * n + C<sub>2</sub> * n + ... + C<sub>10</sub> * n

= (C<sub>1</sub> + C<sub>2</sub> + ... + C<sub>10</sub>) * n

So the total is also `O(n)`, with constant C<sub>1</sub> + ... + C<sub>10</sub>.

Rule of thumb learned: the sum of a constant number of `O(f(n))` functions is `O(f(n))`.

[*] proof of this left to the reader. Hint: there are 10 different values of "sufficient" to consider.

Comment: Nice reply. Thanks! Too bad I can only accept 1 answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, O(10n) = O(n). Also, O(C*n) = O(n), where C is a constant. In this case C is 10. It might seem as O(n^2) if C is equal to n, but this is not true. As C is a constant, it does not
change with n.

Also, note that in summation of complexities, the highest order or the most complex one is considered the overall complexity. In this case it is O(n) + O(n) ... + O(n) ten times. Thus, it is O(n).

Comment: As Steve Jessop points out, the 10 individual constants may be different.  Also it's possibly slightly misleading to say that the highest-order term is "considered" the overall complexity, since that suggests that this is just a convention when in fact it's mathematically implied by the definition of big-Oh.

Comment: E.g. suppose an algorithm takes time D*n^2 + E*n + F, with D positive and E and F unrestricted.  Then set C = D + E' + F', where E' is E if E >= 0 and 0 otherwise, and likewise for F'.  Then C*n^2 = D*n^2 + E'*n^2 + F'*n^2, and for any n >= 1, this is >= D*n^2 + E*n + F because each term considered separately is >=, so the algorithm is O(n^2) with constant C.

Comment: yes, correct. It is mathematically implied and not just "considered". It is my choice of words that went wrong but I meant the same. Thanks for pointing it out.